# Variables in grunt-init

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-init

I'm trying to create a template project with grunt-init and would like to know if it is possible that grunt changes the content of the file by a values that I write down in other configuration file.

Example:

Imagine that I have a configuration file in my project with a date format, something like that:

```
var dateFormat = {%=format %}
```

And, in other configuration file of grunt-init I have something like that:

```
{ "format":"dd/mm/yyy"}
```

How can I configure grunt-init to change format to dd/mm/yyyy when I run it?

Thank you for your time

Comment: http://mattbailey.io/a-beginners-guide-to-grunt/

Comment: Thank you @AvinashBabu but the link is broken

Comment: Ok, sorry. The links works from my phone. It has to be something with the proxy